# Inserting python code in StackOverflow

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have tried to asking question in StackOverflow many times. But fail. As I have error in code part of python.

I was unable to insert python code here.

Can we insert Ipython notebook here?

Comment: You can insert your code as a [mcve], including the traceback, and we should be able run it on our own.

Answer (score 2):

In StackOverflow, the only code that can really be inserted is that of HTML, Javascript, and CSS. Example:

```js
var elem = document.getElementById('section');
elem.innerHTML = "Hello world!"
```

```css
#section
{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="section">

</div>
```

Otherwise, you must use four spaces in order to express a code snippet. Example:

```
i = 0; # there are four spaces in front of this text
```

If you want to dynamically express another language, you must use another site. You can still link to other sites in your posts, however.

This might be a better question for [Stack Overflow Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/).